Puppeteer hung up when clicking button
I have a button on a website that doesn't want to be clicked. Clicking on said button hangs up puppeteer and doesn't actually get clicked. I've used many different ways to click on the button however, they all result in the same way, everything stops and nothing is ran.
Below are some different methods, I've attempted at least 20 ways. Puppeteer debugging really only shows limited logs. Every other portion of the code works, just this button doesn't:
The Button:


<button data-v-1516c9a2="" class="q-btn q-btn-item non-selectable no-outline q-btn--standard q-btn--rectangle bg-primary text-white q-btn--actionable q-focusable q-hoverable q-btn--active" tabindex="0" type="submit" filled=""><span class="q-focus-helper" tabindex="-1"></span><span class="q-btn__content text-center col items-center q-anchor--skip justify-center row"><span class="block">SAVE DETAILS</span></span><!----></button>



console.logs:
0: JSHandle:undefined
1: JSHandle:0
2: JSHandle:123
3: JSHandle:123
4: JSHandle:ASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
Puppeteer Logs:

puppeteer:protocol:RECV ◀ [
puppeteer:protocol:RECV ◀   '{"method":"Runtime.consoleAPICalled","params":{"type":"log","args":[{"type":"undefined"},{"type":"number","value":0,"description":"0"},{"type":"number","value":123,"description":"123"},{"type":"number","value":123,"description":"123"},{"type":"string","value":"ASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"}]... "stackTrace":{"callFrames":[{"functionName":"onSubmit"...

Code V1
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const spanElements = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    for (const spanElement of spanElements) {
        if (spanElement.textContent.trim() === 'SAVE DETAILS') {
            spanElement.click();
                        console.log('found!!');

            break; 
        }
    }
});

Code V2
    try {
        await page.waitForSelector('span', { visible: true });
        const spanSelector = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const spanElements = document.querySelectorAll('span');
            console.log(`Found ${spanElements.length} span elements`);

            for (const spanElement of spanElements) {
                if (spanElement.textContent.trim() === 'SAVE DETAILS') {
                    console.log('Found the SAVE DETAILS span element.');
                    return spanElement; // Return the element itself
                }
            }
            return null;
        });

        if (spanSelector) {
            const result = await page.evaluate(span => {
                span.focus();
                span.click();
                return true;
            }, spanSelector);

            if (result) {
                console.log('Clicked the SAVE DETAILS span element successfully.');
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to click the SAVE DETAILS span element.');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('SAVE DETAILS span element not found.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during script execution:', error);
    }


What page is this running on?

const fetchData = async () => {         browser = await puppeteer.launch({             headless: true,             args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],             devtools: true         });     }     await fetchData();const page = await browser.newPage();

I mean: what website/URL? It's hard to help without seeing the webpage you're running this on that has the unclickable button, or a minimal reproduction of it. Please [edit] your post to share the code updates.

Is there really a button? Try span.closest('button').click()

I've attatched the code to the button. We use quasar for our CSS.
